# Form submitted implicitly even when there are other input element

Tags: html, forms

Based on [HTML specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission):

> 4.10.21.2 Implicit submission
>
> A form element's default button is the first submit button in tree order whose form owner is that form element.
>
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key
> while a text control is focused implicitly submits the form), then
> doing so for a form, whose default button has activation behavior and
> is not disabled, must cause the user agent to fire a click event at
> that default button.
>
> There are pages on the web that are only usable if there is a way to implicitly submit forms, so user agents are strongly encouraged to
> support this.
>
> If the form has no submit button, then the implicit submission mechanism must do nothing if the form has more than one field that
> blocks implicit submission, and must submit the form element from the
> form element itself otherwise.

My expectation is when a form has multiple input elements (and no submit button) then form should not get submitted implicitly when user hits the enter button.

I have a form with a button (not submit button) and multiple input elements.

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/dosomething">
  <input id="validCategory0" name="validCategory" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes
  <input id="validCategory1" name="validCategory" type="radio" value="No">No
  <br/>
  <input id="itemid" type="hidden" />
  <br/> First Name
  <input id="fn" width="200" />
  <br/>
  <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

with above HTML, when cursor is inside the First Name text box and user press enter then the form get submitted. I am not sure why form is getting submitted when there are multiple input elements inside the Form.

I am using Chrome

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/p8n53c1z/)

My observation: If I change `hidden` input element as below then form does NOT get submitted implicitly.

From
`<input id="itemid" type="hidden" />`
To
`<input id="itemid" hidden />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as I said in my comment, you forgot to add the part of the citation that states:

> "For the purpose of the previous paragraph, an element is a field that
> blocks implicit submission of a form element if it is an input element
> whose form owner is that form element and whose type attribute is in
> one of the following states: Text, Search, URL, Telephone, E-mail,
> Password, Local Date and Time, Date, Month, Week, Time, Number"

So inputs like radio buttons, checkboxes, and hidden types aren't on that list, so they don't apply. When you have a second input like `<input id="itemid" type="hidden" />` you explicitly set the type to hidden, so it won't block submission. Removing the type so you have `<input id="itemid" />` *does* stop implicit submission because the default type of an input is `text`, which is on that list, so it stops implicit submission. Similarly, when you switch the input to `<input id="itemid" hidden />` the type is still `text`, so it also stops the implicit submission.

Comment: but hidden works when you have input like `<input id="itemid" hidden />`

Comment: @LP13 In that context, `hidden` is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden), not the type for the input, and since no type is specified, the type default to `text`